# flip a fair coin until $n$ consecutive results, whats the probability of the first and last toss matching?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

lets say i flip a coin until i get $n$ consecutive heads or tails.
whats the probability of the first ever coin i flipped to match the last coin i flipped?
the question also asks, is it exactly $0.5$? more or less?

i figured if the total flips i make is $n$ then $p(e)=1$.
for $n+1$ total flips i get $p(e)=0$.
at the end i got something like $(0.5)^n$ but this just doesnt feel right.

thanks for the help.

Comment: What techniques do you have available? For instance, have you studied Markov chains? Have you tried looking at small values of $n$?

Comment: Just intuitively, the answer should be greater than $\frac 12$:  There's a chance that the run occurs immediately, which is only available to the first face seen.  Working this out for $n=2$ gives $p=\frac 23$ for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Do you know Markov chains? Seeing this problem as a Markov chain might help you. This answer is based on a Markov chain, while it should be understandable without knowing the concept.

Let $E$ be the event that you throw until you get $n$ consecutive results, and the last coin equals the first coin.

You start by throwing your coin until the results change. If you have $n$ or more consecutive results, you terminate and you know that all results were the same.

But if you don't get $n$ consecutive results right from the start, you now have the opposite result from the start. The key observation is that you are now exactly in the opposite situation from the start:

You have flipped one coin (which is opposite to the very first coin), and wait for $n$ consecutive results, and ask yourself, is it the same as this coin (which is opposite to the very first coin). So this has probability $1-P(E)$.

Because the probability to get $n$ consecutive results right from the start is $2^{n-1}$, you get
$$
  P(E) = \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1} + \left[1-\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\right](1-P(E)).
$$
Moving $P(E)$ to the left, we have
$$
  \left[2-\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\right]P(E) = 1
$$
and thus
$$
  P(E) = \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1} > \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac12.
$$

Comment: @NuclearHoagie P(E)=2/3 is also the result. Please read the last line properly. Let's say you started with H (heads) and throw T (tail) for the first time. You're now in the exact same situation as in the beginning, except that you "started" with T, but want to finish with H.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with lulu that intuitively, the answer should be greater than $\frac12$, for the rudimentary case of a streak of $2, Pr = \frac23$

For a streak of $3$, say, let us label states according to the last result of *streaks*, thus $h, h_2, h_3, t, t_2, t_3$

Starting with heads we get the probability equations for heads ultimately "winning" from $h$ as

$h = h_2/2 + t/2 \tag 1$
$t = t_2/2 +h/2 \tag 2$
$t_2 =h/2 + 0*1/2 \tag3$
$h_2= t/2 + 1*1/2 \tag 4$

[Since we are computing probability of a "win" for heads, we are attaching probabiities of $1,0$ for $h_3,t_3$]

The equations yield $h = \Large\frac47$

For a streak of $4$, I get by same process that $p = \Large\frac8{15}$

So the bias would continue for longer streaks but become less and less pronounced.

To generalise by induction, for a streak length of $n$,

P(first result of toss = last result of streak) = $\Large\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n - 1}$